# How is water athermanous?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, water, infrared-radiation, optical-materials

My textbook says that water is an [athermanous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/athermanous) substance i.e. the type of substance which does not transmit any incident heat radiations. But how is that true since water is transparent, light that is radiation passes through it?

Comment: That is for heat radiation, infrared. Visible light does not qualify as heat radiation though its ultimate fate can be heat

Comment: So radio waves, micro waves, x-rays, etc do not qualify for heat radiation either??

Comment: No although upon interaction with an absorber they can still results in the latter heating up. It is energy at the end. Microwave yes, the are in a way "very long wavelength infrared radiation", directly exciting thermal motion.

Comment: Is there some reason for this consideration or is it just by convention??

Comment: It is relevant in the context of transport properties for heat. So an atmosphere of dry N$_2$ and O$_2$ would be diathermanous.

Comment: The article [Transparency of Water in the Visible Range](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Chemical/watabs.html) explains that water absorbs most wavelengths in the electromagnetic spectrum.

Comment: Also take a look at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_radiation just to mitigate my assertions above which are valid but require context. Note that the page deals with black bodies and water is not.